# Joomla: How to insert $jinput to JTable::store via CLI?

Tags: jtable

I got a little problem: I would like to create a form, which content is saved into 2 databases.

```
Field1 -> #__table_1
Field2 -> #__table_2
```

I'm doing this by extending the save-method in my model, which works fine.

But: In my `JTable::store`-method I'm checking the inputs of the user and sometimes I modify other fields according to the value of a specific field. Because not all values are stored in $this (because the fields do not exist in `#__table_1`) I have to work with `$jinput` to get these values.

Well - now I got a problem: I would like to create items by CLI doing this:

```
$data['id'] = NULL;
$data['field1'] = JFactory::getDate();;
$data['field2'] = $json;                        

// Lets store it!   
$row = JTable::getInstance('Ticket','BestiaTable');
$row->bind($data);
$row->check();
$store = $row->store(); 

if($store == true)  return $row->id;

else return false;
```

This does not work because during `bind()` the values that do not exist in `#__table_1` are not available for store-process.

How can I change that? How can I push `field2`'s value to the store-method?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding the question or not, but here's an example of code that I routinely use from the CLI using the model for saving/creating articles in `#__content`, hopefully it will help.

```
$basePath = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_content';
$model = new ContentModelArticle(array('table_path' => $basePath . '/tables'));
$article_id=0;    // 0 will add new article
$data = array(
    'id'    => $article_id,
    'catid' => $myCatId,
    'title' => 'My title',
    'alias' => 'My alias',
    .
    .  // other fields
    .
);
if(!$model->save($data)){
    return false;   // Save failed
}
```